# Spring security doesn't authorize my authenticated requests, but it does through Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have this error related to Spring security that I cannot fix, and it is happening only though the browser. When I try to replicate it through postman, it suddenly works and everything's fine.

I authorized unauthenticated requests for `/login`, and authenticated requests to the rest of the API.

Therefore when I make a call to `/login`, it does let me authenticate.

But, when I make a call to any of my API endpoints that is not `/login`, and I'm already authenticated, my backend returns this strange error:

> [image: ![http failure response]

I don't really know what this error means.

However, when I do the same process through Postman, it works and the endpoint returns what it is supposed to return.

1. Login API call:

> [image: login]

2. Another API call that is not login:

> [image]

As you can see, through Postman it does work well.

But doing the exact same through the Angular UI I'm developing leads to the former error.

My Spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String FRONTEND_URL = "http://localhost:4200/";

private final UserService userService;
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http.cors()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**", "/login-status/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .permitAll()
        .loginPage(FRONTEND_URL + "/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/login-status/success", true)
        .failureUrl("/login-status/failure")
        .and()
    .logout()
        .permitAll();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    return provider;
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(FRONTEND_URL));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
}
```

I hope you could help me cause I'm really stuck with this. I'm a front-end dev who is trying to find my ways to develop a backend, just to learn, but man, shits hard. Thank you very much, and I hope my bad English didn't hurt your eyes too much. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check your port numbers! I am seeing `4200` and `8080`.

Comment: @BlairNangle yes, 4200 for the front end, made with Angular, and 8080 for the backend.

Comment: But in the error that you are complaining about one can read `http://localhost:4200/login`. Shouldn't it be `http://localhost:8080/login`?

Comment: Do you have  Frontend page called login? Is that what you are trying to reach?  The postman request you are doing is hitting the BACKEND because it is going to port 8080, while on your browser you are hitting the FRONTEND on port 4200, so you need to have a ROUTE on your page going to /login

Comment: @SMA yes I do have an Angular page called `/login` on my 4200. That page contains the login form and I intended that form to send a request to my backend to perform login.

Comment: In this case, it is an angular problem.  You most likely do not have a routing path setup `{ path:  'login', component:  LoginComponent}`   https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/11/a-complete-guide-to-routing-in-angular/

Comment: @SMA yes I do have that
```const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];```